# Notes.py error in code

Tags: python

I keep getting an error on this http://bpaste.net/show/146536 on the room.message("Note from %s to %s: %s (%s) " % sender.title(), user.name.title(), message, stamp.LongTimeStampFull(rawtime)) The error is

not enough arguments for format string

notes.one(user.name) is ['sender', 'message', rawtime]

how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for ... in` construct will expect the value after `in` to be an iterable. Now, `notes.one(user.name)` returns `['charles', 'test', time.time()]`, so in the first iteration, only value `charles` will be picked and that will be tried to assign to three values. Thats why it fails.

Instead of

```
for sender, message, rawtime in notes.one(user.name):
    room.message("Note from <i>%s</i> to <i>%s</i>: %s (%s)" % sender.title(), user.name.title(), message, self.LongTimeStampFull(rawtime))
```

do,

```
sender, message, rawtime = notes.one(user.name)
room.message("Note from <i>%s</i> to <i>%s</i>: %s (%s)" % sender.title(), user.name.title(), message, self.LongTimeStampFull(rawtime))
```

Comment: It outputted ['charles', 'test', time.time()]

Comment: So what do i use to fix it?

Comment: @user2950638 Please check now.

Comment: @user2950638 Please update the question with the latest code after the modifications.

Comment: Wait its the room message i did it wrong. I did self.LongTimeStampFull(rawtime) instead of stamp.LongTimeStampFull(rawtime)

Comment: @user2950638 I didn't get your problem now. Please update your question with the actual code used and actual error which you got.